# How can I access heap memory beside using malloc?

Tags: c, heap-memory

Is there a way that you can assign memory from heap without a call to malloc?
Can the following call be affective for it?

```
void* loc = (void*) &heap[end_of_heap];
```

Comment: I need to implement malloc ;)

Comment: @fahad: `malloc()` really needs to be implemented by the OS.  You can't do it from user space without calling some OS function to do the dirty work.  There may be such functions exposed by the OS that are not called `malloc()`, or are used by `malloc()` internally, as mentioned in several answers, but that still isn't the same as doing it yourself in kernel space.

Comment: @fahad: if you're implementing `malloc`, then either you're writing an emulation layer, or an OS. If you're writing an emulation layer, use the memory allocation function of whatever you're sitting above. If you're writing an OS, you need to do something hardware-specific to *define* for yourself what region of memory is going to be "the heap". Consult the memory map for your architecture and choose a suitable physical and/or virtual address range. You could then define something like `char *const the_heap = (char*)0xF00BAA00;`

Comment: This sounds like homework that I had in college.

Comment: @nathon:something which accesses heap without using alloc.h

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The C language itself provides no such functionality. If you only care about Unix systems conforming to a deprecated feature of an old version of the Unix standard (SUSv2 or earlier, if I remember correctly), the `brk` and `sbrk` functions provide this functionality. But you really should not use it unless you're writing very low-level code that will never need to be portable.

Comment: Actually, there is one halfway-portable way to do it: declare globally: `unsigned char heap[1000000000];` or similar and use that.. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

There is no portable way besides malloc and friends, but if you're willing to get platform-specific [sbrk](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) (and `brk`) in old-fashioned Unix (not in current Posix), used to be the underlying syscalls.  Now their manpage says

> Avoid using brk() and sbrk(): the
>   malloc(3) memory allocation package is
>   the
>          portable and comfortable way of allocating memory.

and that advice is surely good (no real advantage in using the old-fashioned syscalls even in platforms that supply them).  `mmap` of some `/dev/` is a totally different way for some modern Unix versions, Windows has its own totally different "win32 API calls" for the purpose, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to get a pointer to new and valid heap memory other than using a heap allocating function.  You cannot simply add a pointer into the heap at the end of an existing pointer and expect to *reliably* access it.

Answer (score 3):

The Standard does not say anything about heap (search it, if you don't believe this). An implementation is not even required to have a heap (as we commonly know it).

However, the short answer to your question is, no in Standard C. Unless of course you use a platform specific API. Typically, OS APIs sometimes do give you some leeway as to accessing memory.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access heap reliably without malloc, but there are alternatives for memory allocation.

If you're trying to get finer control over memory allocations, you can use other memory managers like [bget memory allocator](http://www.fourmilab.ch/bget/). Here you grab a huge chunk of heap (the maximum memory requiredment anticipated + some overhead) using `malloc` and pass it to the bget using `bpool`. From there on, call `bget` instead of `malloc` to allocate memory and `brel` to free it. bget is [reportedly better](http://www.mail-archive.com/dropbear@ucc.asn.au/msg00586.html) in avoiding memory fragmentation.